# Sprout Email: "Unable to save recipient."

Tags: plugin-sproutemail

Craft 2.5.2754, Sprout Email 2.01, fresh plugin install.

In attempting to use the Recipients feature, I created a new group (Contact Form Recipients) and hit the Add Recipient button. I filled out the email address, first, and last names, but it keeps saying "Unable to save recipient."

The error log says: `Craft\SproutEmail_DefaultMailerRecipientModel->recipientLists failed validation: Recipient Lists cannot be blank.`

I added a few more lists to be safe; no luck.

Is it possible I'm missing something, or is there a recommended fix or workaround for this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug and has been fixed in [Sprout Email v2.0.2](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email/updates#release-v2.0.2).